# Run Rails migrations in a sandbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to prepare a complex migration that moves data between tables. If I do it wrong I may end up with a strange data in the DB. Is there a trick to run it in a sandbox and revert the DB to the previous state? I know I can backup and restore DB, but I wonder if there is any simpler solution.

Comment: Why not use the test db ? or rails c --sandbox -> run your script in the console -> come back. (Just crossed my mind)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your SQL but you can just run it in a Transaction - that way if anything goes wrong along the way your tables won't be corrupted

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  # Do stuff
end
```

Note that this does not help if you did something wrong but there are no errors during execution - so I would still advise to create a database backup before. Running it in a real sandbox is impossible unless you do all your table translations etc on temporary tables (INSERT INTO is your friend here) and only copy them back onto the live ones once done - and still not guarantee that it's OK.. Backups are your friend here :)

PS: Depending on your Database and storage engine Transactions will not always work. Some things can't be done in a transaction in certain database systems. This is called `implicit commit` where the Database commits your changes implicitly when some commands are issued (so you loose the ability to roll back if anything goes wrong afterwards. For mysql you can see the list of these implicit commit commands here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html
 One of these is `alter_table` which is bad for your use case I gather

Comment: Aren't migrations run in transaction by default anyway?

Answer (score -1):

Restoring the DB should be the simplest method as it is very fast to restore your DB to the last stable state.

Another way that I can think of is to create different environment and different database.

For example, you can create an environment called staging and then run the migration as below:

```
RAILS_ENV=staging rake db:migrate db:seed
```

A different environment may be better if your migration is really complex which includes source code changes, etc.

Using git, you can also branch off this migration so that you can always revert back to the original state if anything goes wrong.

```
git checkout -b new_migration

// do your migration and create new environment file eg. /config/environments/staging.rb   
RAILS_ENV=staging rake db:migrate db:seed

// check your migration
// if everything is okay
// merge back to main branch and run the migration for real
```

Comment: restoring to the *seed* db is very quick. If you're running a migration that alters data the restoring a copy of a db with real data can take hours. the question of IF you should alter data with migrations is valid, but many do with good reasoning.

Comment: therefore it is better to do the migration in another environment, say staging, which does not affect your production data in any way.